# How can i delete last row in Datagridview, XML database?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, xml-database

when i try to delete last row on Datagridview and XML database i cant delete.
I can delete all of items normal but last row cant be deleted.

Here my delete button:

```
private void silbtn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument x = XDocument.Load(@"../../Data/gemi1/gemi1s2.xml");
        x.Root.Elements().Where(a => a.Element("id").Value == siltxt2.Text).Remove();
        x.Save(@"../../Data/gemi1/gemi1s2.xml");
        yukle();
    }
```

Comment: If your problem is not resolved, please take a screenshot of your current problem. Please tell me what's `yukle();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridView_AllowUserToAddRows) to false.

Set this property so that the last empty row is not displayed.

Comment: You also can refer to [How to: Prevent Row Addition and Deletion in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/prevent-row-addition-and-deletion-datagridview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).